# protractor/jasmine log level at headless mode

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'am satisfy with log level at "normal" mode of Protractor. But at headless mode there are some rows ("INFO:CONSOLE"), which are not present at normal mode.
see, this is part of console log:
`√ clicking on the shopping cart button`
`[0326/145348.203:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Environment:  TEST", source: https://xxxxx/main.912238b1bc9babccd4d6.js (2)`
`[0326/145348.303:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Token change - reading cart", source: xxxxx/main.912238b1bc9babccd4d6.js (2)` 
First row is OK.
But how to remove "INFO:CONSOLE" rows from logs?
I can't find where.
**here is my protractor.conf.js:**

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
let baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4200';
let project = 'e2eUsnl';
const config = {
  params: {
    baseUrl,
    project,
  },
  allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
  specs: [],
  suites: {
    homePageLinks: './src/**/homepageLinks-spec.ts',
    userSetting: './src/**/userSetting-spec.ts',
  },
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--headless',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
        // '--start-maximized',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--lang=cs-CZ'
      ]
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 240000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: { displayStacktrace: true }
    }));
  }
};
```

Comment: add your config

Comment: @Sergey,
here it is, the post was updated.

Comment: not sure where it's coming from. jasmine spec reporter is not supposed to print these messages